# VS Code Python Debug uses virtual files rather than actual source code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, debugging

## Configurations

- Python plugin (used to be called Pylance)
- Standard VS Code debugger
- PDM / `pyproject.toml` package format
- installing package locally

I can provide other config details if needed, but I think they are irrelevant.

## Issue

I have a package which has a module that is calling a function in another module. Instead of calling the *actual* source code that I am editing and which exists in the repo, it is calling the files used in the virtual environment. Ie,

- Function 1 in module A is called, which calls function 2 in module B.
- However, instead of module B being called, *the install of module B in my virtual environment is being called*.

  - Module B in actual source: `src/phxfakedata/utils/traverse.py`
  - Module B in virtual environment: `.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/phxfakedata/utils/traverse.py`
  - Module A is being debugged from the actual repo, `src/phxfakedata/generate/generate.py`, but when it delves into Module B, it is calling the module in the virtual environment.
- This is a problem because I start working on the problem -- which is in module B, but only visible when being called from module A -- and then I realize that all of the fixes which I've made where done on the virtual environment file, so then when I run the (properly isolated) tests, they all fail because all the work I did was on the wrong file.

## Solution

I'm hoping there is some sort of configuration *within VS Code* where I can tell it, please don't use the virtual environment, but use the actual code.

I thought this was being I wasn't actually installing as an editable package, but that doesn't seem to be the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following setting to ignore modules you don't want to get:

```json
    "python.analysis.exclude": [],
```

> Paths of directories or files that should not be included. These override the include directories, allowing specific subdirectories to be excluded. Note that files in the exclude paths may still be included in the analysis if they are referenced (imported) by source files that are not excluded. Paths may contain wildcard characters ** (a directory or multiple levels of directories), * (a sequence of zero or more characters), or ? (a single character). If no exclude paths are specified, Pylance automatically excludes the following: `**/node_modules`, `**/__pycache__`, `.git` and any virtual environment directories.

Comment: Cool, thanks!  Simple and easy, perfect!!